# Bookdown: Start chapter numbers at 0 instead of 1?

Tags: bookdown

I have a Gitbook with a series of lab assignments.  The first is a "practice" assignment.  I would like that chapter of the Gitbook to be numbered 0, so that the rest of the chapter numbers will refer to the graded labs (1 thru 6).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could suppress the chapter numbering of the first section using the `{-}` after the title

```
# First unnumbered chapter {-}

# Numbered Chapter
```

If you are making the bookdown document into a PDF,  you can actually just use LaTeX commands directly within the body of the document:

```
 \setcounter{section}{-1}
```

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107470/122325 for more details

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have subsections in this chapter that I was hoping to number with 0.1, 0.2, etc.  And this is intended as an html GitBook.  It would be great setcounter worked for this context too.

Comment: Using the `{-}` should work if you want the 0.1, 0.2. I've not checked this though as I'm on my phone